# Color switching button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I wanted to build a Javascript code which changes the background color of the body when a button is clicked. The console says that `body.style.background` is not a function. Can you tell what was the mistake in my code?

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "pink"];
var i = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (i < colors.length) {
       i++;
  } else if (i == colors.length) {
       i = 0;
  }
 body.style.background("colors[i]");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `body.style.background = colors[i];` as `background` is a property of `style` so it should be assigned with the value of the color instead of calling it as a function and passing argument into it.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "pink"];
var i = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (i < colors.length) {
       i++;
  } else if (i == colors.length) {
       i = 0;
  }
 body.style.background = colors[i];
});
```

```html
<body> 
  some content
  <button>Click</button>
</body>
```

You can further refactor your code to look much simpler:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "pink"];
var i = 0;
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
 i = i < colors.length ? ++i : 0;
 body.style.background = colors[i];
});
```

```html
<body> 
  some content
  <button>Click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: @AKHILREDDY glad to help :)